# How to solve ValueError When save ModelMultipleChoiceField in ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

My model.py:

```
class RelayAddress(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default=0)
    sister_relay_relation = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='RelaySisterRelation',symmetrical=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_time = int(time.time())
        super(RelayAddress,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class RelaySisterRelation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default=0)
    relay = models.ForeignKey(RelayAddress,related_name="relay")
    sister_relay = models.ForeignKey(RelayAddress,related_name="sister_relay")
```

My admin.py

```
class RelaySisterRelationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    relay=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=u'relay',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),queryset=RelayAddress.objects.all())
    sister_relay=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=u'sister_relay',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),queryset=RelayAddress.objects.all())

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RelaySisterRelationForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

And my view.py is null, then I get a ValueError:

```
Cannot assign "[<RelayAddress: RelayAddress object>]": "RelaySisterRelation.relay" must be a "RelayAddress" instance.
```

And how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`RelaySisterRelation.relay` is a ForeignKey to `RelayAddress` meaning it can only store a references to one `RelayAddress` but your `RelaySisterRelationForm.relay` uses `ModelMultipleChoiceField` which is for many-to-many relations so returns a (potentially empty) list of `RelayAddress` instances.

Comment: So，How to sovle this P?

Comment: Use a `ModelChoiceField` instead of a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

Comment: thanks a lot!  but I have already use "ManyToManyField" in class RelayAddress, and how should I do in '''class RelaySisterRelation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default=0)
    relay = models.ForeignKey(RelayAddress,related_name="relay")
    sister_relay = models.ForeignKey(RelayAddress,related_name="sister_relay")'''        I want to get more than one data from chechbox,so I canot use "ModelChoiceField".

Comment: I'm not certain what you are trying to achieve, so it's hard to give you an answer.

Comment: when click the "save" button,I want get more than one data form the checkbox though "cleaned_data['sister_relay']",then full permutate these data,and save in pairs.so the error happend "...ValueError..." as above.    sorry for my bad statement.