# Django: ValueError (must be a category instance) when saving a ModelMultipleChoiceField with CheckboxSelectMultiple based on a ForeignKey to my Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm getting a ValueError: Cannot assign "[Category: cat1],[Category: cat2] ": "ProfileUser.chosencategories" must be a "Category" instance. When attempting to save my ModelForm.

My form is as follows:

```
class ProfileUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
        model = ProfileUser
        fields = ('field1', 'field2','field3','field4', 'chosencategories')


  chosencategories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                     queryset=Category.objects.all(), to_field_name="name")
```

My View is:

```
@login_required
def create_user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method=='POST':
        profile_user_form=ProfileUserForm(request.POST)
        if profile_user_form.is_valid():
            new_user_profile=profile_user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user_profile.user=user
            new_user_profile.save()

            return render(request, 'accounts/user_profile_registered.html', 
                                    {'new_user_profile':new_user_profile})
    else:
        profile_user_form=ProfileUserForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/create_user_profile.html', 
                                {'profile_user_form':profile_user_form})
```

My Models are:

```
class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    field3 = models.DateField(blank=True)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    chosencategories=models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, related_name='categorieschosen')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORIES)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

I want to allow users to select multiple instances of the Category object and have these instances saved to their profile within the chosencategories attribute. I have set up the Models and Form Fields to that effect.

I have looked at the following questions:

[Django form not saving with ModelChoiceField - ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117180/django-form-not-saving-with-modelchoicefield-foreignkey)

[Django: ValueError when saving an instance to a ForeignKey Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081593/django-valueerror-when-saving-an-instance-to-a-foreignkey-field)

[How to solve ValueError When save ModelMultipleChoiceField in ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565638/how-to-solve-valueerror-when-save-modelmultiplechoicefield-in-modelform)

All of which touch on the topic without providing a clear cut solution. From what I've read, it seems that I need to provide some sort of reference to the Category object before my view calls "if profile_user_form.is_valid():" - I am stuck on what exactly I need to include and why.

All help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: According to your models `ProfileUser` can have only one category as `chosencategories`. So it is impossible to use `MultipleChoiceField` here.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chosencategories` should be a `ManyToManyField` instead of `ForeignKey` if you want to assign multiple categories to `ProfileUser`

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I changed ForeignKey to ManyToManyField and then added: 

user_profile_form.save_m2m()

to my view.

Comment: Also, if anyone is stuck on anything similar I found this blog post to be very helpful: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/6/23/django-m2m-modelform.html